# Calling OCMStub and OCMReject on the same method

Tags: objective-c, xctest, ocmock

I've been attempting to write some fail fast tests using OCMReject. However I've found that if OCMStub is used in conjunction with OCMReject, this test will pass

```
id _mockModel = OCMProtocolMock( @protocol( CTPrefModelProtocol));
//It doesn't seem to matter what order these two are in, the test behaves the same
OCMStub([_mockModel getPreferences]);
OCMReject([_mockModel getPreferences]);
[_mockModel getPreferences];
```

Even though it should clearly fail because I'm calling the function that I've set in the OCMReject method.

I realise I can just stub getPreferences whenever I'm expecting a result from it and remove it from this test, but largely that means if I've set a stub on getPreferences in my setUp method, any test that calls `OCMReject([_mockModel getPreferences])` will just be ignored.

Why am I not able to use OCMStub and OCMReject together? Is it because OCMStub alters getPreferences somehow and as a result whenever I call this method, it actually calls some other method instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently I can't read. Reading through the OCMock 3 Documentation, under the limitations heading **10.2**

> Setting up expect after stub on the same method does not work

```
id mock = OCMStrictClassMock([SomeClass class]);
OCMStub([mock someMethod]).andReturn(@"a string");
OCMExpect([mock someMethod]);

/* run code under test */

OCMVerifyAll(mock); // will complain that someMethod has not been called
```

> The code above first sets up a stub for someMethod and afterwards an
>   expectation for the same method. Due to the way mock objects are
>   currently implemented any calls to someMethod are handled by the stub.
>   This means that even if the method is called the verify fails. It is
>   possible to avoid this problem by adding andReturn to the expect
>   statement. You can also set up a stub after the expect.

I suspect this same limitation exists for OCMReject as well. Hopefully this helps equally blind people like myself. A [link to the documentation](http://ocmock.org/reference/) for the lazy.

Comment: You may want to try OCMockito to see if it helps with this particular test.

Comment: Oh, I've not tried OCMockito, I'll have to give it a go, Thanks. Do you prefer it over OCMock? or is it just more useful in some situations?

Comment: I wrote OCMockito, but each has different strengths.